# Getting error: `/usr/bin/veracrypt: No such file or directory` after installing veracrypt

Tags: linux, pi-3b+, software-installation, bash

I am trying to install the `armv7` version of Veracrypt on my Raspberry Pi. I downloaded it from: https://launchpad.net/veracrypt/trunk/1.21/+download/veracrypt-1.21-raspbian-setup.tar.bz2, unzipped and ran `./veracrypt-1.21-setup-console-armv7`. But after installing the software and executing Veracrypt from the command-line, I am presented with the following error:

`/usr/bin/veracrypt: No such file or directory`

The permissions of `/usr/bin`: `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 69632 Feb  3 11:26 /usr/bin/`

The permissions of `/usr/bin/veracrypt`: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 1000 1000 2789700 Jul 16  2017 /usr/bin/veracrypt`

Comment: `veracrypt` is not part of the default repository. How exactly do you install it from where?

Comment: @Ingo I downloaded it from: https://launchpad.net/veracrypt/trunk/1.21/+download/veracrypt-1.21-raspbian-setup.tar.bz2, unzipped and ran `./veracrypt-1.21-setup-console-armv7`.

Comment: Did you run ```sudo ./veracrypt-1.21-setup-console-armv7```?

Comment: @Dougie yeah I did and the error persists

Comment: try running ```/usr/bin/veracrypt -v /home/pi/cryptfile passwordforcryptfile```

Comment: @Dougie it comes back with "/usr/bin/veracrypt: No such  file or directory."